# reveal div after form submit

Tags: forms, function, submit

On my Wordpress website, I have an input field where the user types their email address and then clicks "Submit" to submit their email to my google spreadsheet (using a google form on Google Drive).

I also have a button that opens a popup when the button is clicked (I'm using the SimpModal plugin for Wordpress).

Is there a way to integrate both functions, so that I will only have 1 button that accomplishes both results?  (i.e. When the user fills out their email address and then clicks the submit button, it will submit their email address to the google form, and also open the popup window?)

Here's my code:

```
<!--This gets rid of the google confirmation page-->
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none; width:0px; height:0px;" onload="if(submitted){window.location='#';}"></iframe>

<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/XXXXX/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" onsubmit="" target="hidden_iframe">


<input type="text" name="entry.2005577686" value="" id="entry_2005577686">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >

<div id="button-to-open-popup"><a href="#">
<img src="/landing-pg-button-black.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>

</form>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple! If you don't have jQuery, please import it somewhere in your code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

And then change the onsubmit in the form tag...

```
<form ... onsubmit="$('#button-to-open-popup').click();return true;" ...>
```

Tada!

Comment: Just so that I can better understand how this works -- what does "return true" mean?

Comment: Nothing :P No, but if you return false, the form won't submit, and you usually use onsubmit to make sure the form is filled out, and then do return false/true depending on if the form is complete or not, so it's just to make it clearer. But actually, it maybe is clearer without it.. return true is the default, so there is no need for that one.. :)

Comment: So, the key code that we added here was "onsubmit="$('#button-to-open-popup').click();" which basically means: "when the form is submitted, do whatever you would have done if #button-to-open-popup was clicked"?

Comment: Oh no! It just says: "When submitting the form, click the element with id 'button-to-open-popup'" :)

Comment: But yeah, the key code was "onsubmit="$('#button-to-open-popup').click();".

Comment: Uh oh... It does work to open the popup, but I have another form that is displayed within the popup, and now that form has disappeared. I think somehow that when I added your line of code, clicking on "Submit" now submits BOTH forms... does that make sense? How can we tell it to only submit the first form?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe.. try to put your popup code and it's form outside the first form.. And I hope you did change your first form's onsubmit attribute, not just adding the line I wrote? All these unexpected errors when programming...

Comment: Nevermind! Problem solved. The problem was that both of my forms had the same id. :)

Comment: How can I add jQuery code into the "onsubmit" part of the tag that says: If the email field contains an email address, submit the form and show the popup. Otherwise ("else"), display an alert box that says "Please enter your email address"?

Comment: ... onsubmit="if (/*check code that returns true if success*/) {$('#button-to-open-popup').click();return true;} alert('Wrong email?');return false;" ...